# How to read Json result back from httprequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I making a get request to Zoho support endpoint, and the result for this call can be of two different structures. Either a result with error . which should look something like below(if the search results are none).

```
{
 "response": {
    "uri": "/api/json/accounts/getrecordsbysearch",
    "error": {
       "code": 4832,
       "message": "There is no data to show"
    }
  }
}
```

Or if the search results has one or more objects to be returned. It would look like:

```
{
 "response": {
"result": {
  "Accounts": {
    "row": {
      "no": "1",
      "fl": [
        {
          "val": "ACCOUNTID",
          "content": "8046200"
        },
        {
          "val": "URI",
          "content": "/support/"
        },
        {
          "val": "IsCommented",
          "content": "false"
        },
        {
          "val": "Username",
          "content": "Outdoo"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
"uri": "/api/json/accounts/getrecordsbysearch"
}
}
```

What would be the best way for me to parse the result, and do the following
:

1. An error : If so run Method A
2. if there is just one record that returns, then run Method B
3. If there is more than one record, then run Method C.

I am not too sure which will be the best approach to parse the json and check the content

Comment: You can create two C# types: one for result and one for error. First try to deserialize result. If reult is NULL than try to deserialize as error type. Not sure did I understand you properly.

Comment: @kat1330 : You got me correctly, and thats exactly what I had in mind too. But isnt there a better way to do , than creating multiple classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a class structure like the one below(Result class and classes below that structure were removed to make this example shorter), the json string always gets deserialized and you can then check if the error class has a value.

```
public class Error
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
    public string uri { get; set; }
    public Error error { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Response response { get; set; }
}
```

Deserialize:

```
var o = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped